# Flutter cannot find the path that I already add in pubsec.yaml

Tags: flutter

```
void executeTreatments() {
  var treatmentList = [];
  File('lib/asset/treatments.txt')
      .openRead()
      .map(utf8.decode)
      .transform(new LineSplitter())
      .forEach((l) => print(l));
}
```

The error I get is "[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'lib/assets/treatments.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MzWY.png)"

Answer (score 1):

Add assets in your pub spec.yaml finlike this.

```
  assets:
    - assets/
```

and then use it like this.

```
File('assets/treatments.txt')
```